# nopCommerce : how to have a shopping cart pre-filled with 2 products?

Tags: shopping-cart, nopcommerce

Basically I want the user to land on a pre-filled shopping cart with 2 products. I see the `ShoppingCartController` has the `AddProductToCart` action. Is there a way to call successively `AddProductToCart` twice, and being after redirected to the Shopping Cart ?

Also on the client side, there `AjaxCart.addproductvarianttocart` associated with the button `Add to Cart`. So what is the best way to achieve a prefilled shopping cart with `nopCommerce` ? I am working with nopCommerce `2.65`

Comment: when you want to add that 2 product in Users Cart? i mean when user frist time register or just for 1 time you want to add??

Comment: It is for selling a software. I want by default the shopping cart to present the buyer with 2 items (the software plus an option). He can then choose the qty and then click Check Out.

There will be no store when you can add others products to the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little in the code, I have used the following modification, and it works so far :

In the project `Nop.Web.Framework`, in the file `WebWorkContext.cs`, there is a function `GetCurrentCustomer` who is used among others to insert first-time non-registered visitor into the DB :

```
// create guest if not exists
if (customer == null || customer.Deleted || !customer.Active)
{
    customer = _customerService.InsertGuestCustomer();
}
```

After InsertGuestCustomer, I am creating some `Products` and adding them to the shopping cart with `customer.ShoppingCartItems.Add(new ShoppingCartItem(){...});`

After the visitor registers, the shopping cart is already filled, and it can then be checked out.

Any insight whether this is the right way or not ?